# Is it possible to generate executable from Windows RT?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8

Is it possible to generate any sort of executable from within Windows RT and .Net 4.5? In the desktop I know CSharpCodeProvider could be used, but it seems to not be allowed in Windows RT. The goal is to make an IDE for C#.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played with it myself, but I think [Project Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) would be a good fit.  You should be able to call those APIs from a WinRT front end, I think.

Answer (score 0):

WinRT is not intended (as of today), to create such kind of applications, the closest is the eval function on Javascript, but it's the only one.